# Grails 2.1.1 - How to develop a plugin with an AstTransformer?

Tags: java, grails, grails-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, grails-2.0

I want to replace the auto injected `log` object, which is of type `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` with an object of type `org.slf4j.Logger`, so that I can use it properly with Logback.

Therefore I need to create a `...Transformer` class (written in Java) - that's what I got from Graeme Rocher over at the "grails-user" mailing list. I'm also aware that I have to pack this `...Transformer` class within a plugin and make it a *.jar archive which I can load within the `lib/` folder of the plugin. But I guess I'm doing something wrong here as I have the class, along with a `META-INF` folder which contains the `MANIFEST.MF` file as well as another folder `services` which holds the following file `org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation` which holds just one String: the canonical name of the `...Transformer` class.

Now, if I try to do a `grails clean` everything is fine, BUT if I try to run `grails package-plugin` the console comes up with a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Clipping from Stacktrace:

```
| Packaging Grails application...

| Error Fatal error during compilation org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Could not instantiate global transform class my.package.ast.LoggingTransformation specified at jar:file:/C:/Source/MyGrailsAST/lib/replace-logging-logback-ast.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.ast.LoggingTransformation

1 error

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Could not instantiate global transform class my.package.ast.LoggingTransformation specified at jar:file:/C:/Source/MyGrailsAST/lib/replace-logging-logback-ast.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.ast.LoggingTransformation
```

Does anybody have some experience with Grails plugins which handle with `AstTransformer` and could give me some advice on this? Is there a good tutorial out there which I haven't seen so far?

Please let me know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, after some research, browsing and finally asking at the Grails Mailing List (see the mailing list archives at: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-user-f1312389.html I found a solution.

my goal was to create a **Globals ASTTransformation**, to inject a `org.slf4j.Logger` object instead of the usual `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` object into every Artefact class without annotation.

so, here are the steps:

I created Java class similar to https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-logging/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/logging/LoggingTransformer.java but with my own implementation of the `org.slf4j.Logger` object. It is crucial that you place the Java.class under the following package: `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler` as

> Grails scans for classes that are annotated with @AstTransformer in this package. (*Graeme Rocher*)

and pack it into a JAR along with its `MANIFEST.MF` file within the `META-INF/` folder. A `META-INF/services` directory with all its stuff is not needed as *Graeme Rocher* stated:

> You do not need the META-INF/services stuff and I would remove it as it is probably complicating matters.

So, I guess this statement was more related to my specific problem as I only have one `@AstTransformer` class within my plugin, but that's just a guess. And I haven't searched for further informations on this topic. *Maybe some other developer here who needs this could do some research and share his solution within this thread...*

The JAR should be imported to the plugin and placed under the `lib/` directory. After this you should be able to do `grails clean`, `grails compile` and `grails package-plugin`.

If you want to replace the `log` implementation, as I did, you should exclude the `grails-logging` and `grails-plugin-log4j` JARs from your designated project's classpath. This is done in the `BuildConfig.groovy` file:

```
inherits("global") {
  excludes "grails-plugin-log4j", "grails-logging"
}
```

Now install your plugin `grails install-plugin \path\to\plugin.zip` and everthing should work as expected.

Hope this helps...